# Making Dependency Property registration strongly typed

Tags: c#, design-patterns, generics, wpf, extension-methods

I've been working on another builder, this time for the `DependencyProperty` because it's `object`-based. This means that every parameter is an `object` and thus their usage is inconvenient (requires casting).

In my experiment I tried to make its creation easier and at the same time generic. This is what it looks like.

---

The core class is the generic `DependencyPropertyBuilder`. It allows you to set all properties of a `DependencyProperty` by providing strongly typed methods.

*The line breaks in method signatures are to avoid horizontal scrolling.*

```
class DependencyPropertyBuilder<T, TValue> where T : DependencyObject
{
    private readonly string _name;
    private readonly Type _propertyType;
    private readonly Type _ownerType;
    private readonly PropertyMetadata _propertyMetadata;
    private ValidateValueCallback _validateValueCallback;

    public DependencyPropertyBuilder(
        string name, 
        Type propertyType, 
        Type ownerType
    )
    {
        _name = name;
        _propertyType = propertyType;
        _ownerType = ownerType;
        _propertyMetadata = new PropertyMetadata();
    }

    public DependencyPropertyBuilder<T, TValue> ValidateValue(
        Func<TValue, bool> validateValueCallback
    )
    {
        _validateValueCallback = new ValidateValueCallback(
            value => validateValueCallback(
                (TValue)value
            )
        );
        return this;
    }

    public DependencyPropertyBuilder<T, TValue> DefaultValue(
        TValue defaultValue
    )
    {
        _propertyMetadata.DefaultValue = defaultValue;
        return this;
    }

    public DependencyPropertyBuilder<T, TValue> PropertyChanged(
        Action<T, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs<TValue>> propertyChangedCallback
    )
    {
        _propertyMetadata.PropertyChangedCallback = new PropertyChangedCallback(
            (sender, e) =>
                propertyChangedCallback((T)sender,
                new DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs<TValue>(e)
            )
        );
        return this;
    }

    public DependencyPropertyBuilder<T, TValue> CoerceValue(
        Func<T, TValue, TValue> coerceValueCallback
    )
    {
        _propertyMetadata.CoerceValueCallback = new CoerceValueCallback(
            (d, baseValue) =>
                coerceValueCallback((T)d,
                (TValue)baseValue
            )
        );
        return this;
    }

    public DependencyProperty ToDependencyProperty()
    {
        return DependencyProperty.Register(
            _name,
            _propertyType,
            _ownerType,
            _propertyMetadata,
            _validateValueCallback
        );
    }

    public static implicit operator DependencyProperty(
        DependencyPropertyBuilder<T, TValue> builder
    ) 
       => builder.ToDependencyProperty();
}
```

---

The core builder is accompanied by another non-generic builder that provides two overloads of the `Register` method that gather the mandatory information about a property via generics or Expressions.

```
class DependencyPropertyBuilder
{
    public static DependencyPropertyBuilder<T, TValue> Register<T, TValue>(
        string propertyName
    ) 
    where T : DependencyObject
    {
        var propertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);

        return new DependencyPropertyBuilder<T, TValue>(
            name: propertyName,
            propertyType: propertyInfo.PropertyType,
            ownerType: propertyInfo.DeclaringType
        );
    }

    public static DependencyPropertyBuilder<T, TValue> Register<T, TValue>(
        Expression<Func<TValue>> expression
    ) 
    where T : DependencyObject
    {
        var memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;

        return new DependencyPropertyBuilder<T, TValue>(
            name: memberExpression.Member.Name,
            propertyType: ((PropertyInfo)memberExpression.Member).PropertyType,
            ownerType: ((PropertyInfo)memberExpression.Member).DeclaringType
        );
    }
}
```

---

In order to provide strongly typed `EventArgs` for the `PropertyChangedCallback` I created a generic wrapper:

```
struct DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs<T>
{
    private readonly DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs _e;
    public DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs(
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e
    )
    {
        _e = e;
    }

    public T OldValue => (T)_e.OldValue;

    public T NewValue => (T)_e.NewValue;

    public DependencyProperty Property => _e.Property;
}
```

---

I also tried to make the wrapper-property usage more *natural* and created two more extensions for the getter and setter. They virtually flip the order of operations.

```
static class DependencyPropertyExtensions
{
    public static T GetValue<T>(
        this DependencyProperty dependencyProperty, 
        DependencyObject dependencyObject
    )
    {
        return (T)dependencyObject.GetValue(dependencyProperty);
    }

    public static void SetValue(
        this DependencyProperty dependencyProperty, 
        DependencyObject dependencyObject, 
        object value
    )
    {
        dependencyObject.SetValue(dependencyProperty, value);
    }
}
```

---

## Example usage

As Dependency Properties work only with a Dependency Objects I created one for testing that defines such a property:

```
class TestObject : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CountProperty =
        DependencyPropertyBuilder
        .Register<TestObject, int>(nameof(TestObject.Count))
        // Alternatively with an expression
        // requires #pragma warning disable 1720 
        //.Register<TestObject, int>(() => default(TestObject).Count)
        .DefaultValue(5)
        .PropertyChanged((sender, e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{e.Property.Name} = {e.OldValue} --> {e.NewValue}");
        })
        .ValidateValue(value => value < 10);

    // Default usage
    public int Count
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(CountProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CountProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using DependencyPropertyExtensions
    public int Count2
    {
        get { return CountProperty.GetValue<int>(this); }
        set { CountProperty.SetValue(this, value); }
    }
}
```

In the Console:

```
var testObject = new TestObject();
testObject.Count.Dump(); // 5, as this is the default value

testObject.Count2 = 8; // PropertyChanged kicks-in and prints to the Console
testObject.Count2.Dump(); // 8

testObject.Count2 = 12; // throws '12' is not a valid value for property 'Count'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were to nitpick I would point out a couple of limitations:

1. You can no longer return `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` from `CoerceValueCallback` since return value now is strongly typed.
2. You can not set other types of metadata, such as `FrameworkPropertyMetadata`.
3. Not exactly a limitation, but I feel like current API adds a lot of boiler-plate code, which is a common problem with builder pattern. I think I would rather write

   ```
   .Metadata(5, ChangedCallback, CoerceValueCallback)
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   .DefaultValue(5).PropertyChanged(ChangedCallback).ValidateValue(CoerceValueCallback);
   ```

   but maybe its just me.

All in all, I think that if you decide to use this builder, you should stick to that decision and use it *everywhere*. This means that you will have to add support for all possible registration scenarios to your API. Otherwise I feel like its going to be really confusing for a reader to see half the properties registered using builder and half registered without it.

P.S. Otherwise your code looks pretty clean to me.

P.P.S. I would use `Count` just because it does not require any prior knowledge about your extensions, therefore it is easier to understand for fellow developers (and because I'm too lazy to modify re-sharper templates). However if I were to pretend that I know nothing about WPF, I would say that `Count2` looks cleaner.

P.P.P.S. It just occurred to me that the main advantage of your registration lies in strong typed event handlers. After all `Register<TestObject>` syntax does not add any additional "safety" compared to regular `Register(typeof(TestObject))`. So what you could do is this. Instead of overwriting entire registration process, you could extend/wrap `PropertyMetadata` class. I see this as a compromise approach, where you do both: keep the <s>ugly</s> familiar syntax, but add type safety to event handlers, if it is needed.

Comment: I like nitpicking ;-) I think the `ProperetyMetadata` part in the original implementation does not add any value and just confuses. It's all about the property you create anyway so the _metadata_ isn't necessary. I like the point about the `UnsetValue` and the `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` and I need to do some research about it. Yes, I plan to use it everywhere because I find the metadata and casting very confusing and and redundant. The purpose of the new `Register` is to extract all necessary information for registration automatically rather then specifying three parameters manually.

Comment: Ok, I understand my mistakes now. There's no way around a distinction between various PropertyMetadata types which I wasn't aware they existed. The `UnsetValue` needs its place too.