# Making Dependency Property registration strongly typed v2

Tags: c#, design-patterns, generics, wpf, extension-methods

This is my second attempt to create a strongly typed builder for the Dependency Property. I've improved the two main weaknesses of the [previous](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/150791/making-dependency-property-registration-strongly-typed) version which were:

- Can specify only `PropertyMatadata` but not `FrameworkPropertyMetadata`
- Can coerce value but not cancel the operation with `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue`

---

The `PropertyMatadata` can now be created with its own builder.

```
class PropertyMetadataBuilder<T, TValue> where T : DependencyObject
{
    private readonly PropertyMetadata _propertyMetadata;

    internal PropertyMetadataBuilder()
    {
        _propertyMetadata = new PropertyMetadata();
    }

    public PropertyMetadataBuilder<T, TValue> DefaultValue(
        TValue defaultValue
    )
    {
        _propertyMetadata.DefaultValue = defaultValue;
        return this;
    }

    public PropertyMetadataBuilder<T, TValue> PropertyChanged(
        Action<T, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs<TValue>> propertyChangedCallback
    )
    {
        _propertyMetadata.PropertyChangedCallback = new PropertyChangedCallback(
            (sender, e) =>
                propertyChangedCallback((T)sender,
                new DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs<TValue>(e)
            )
        );
        return this;
    }

    public PropertyMetadataBuilder<T, TValue> PropertyChanging(
        Action<T, PropertyChangingEventArgs<TValue>> coerceValueCallback
    )
    {
        _propertyMetadata.CoerceValueCallback = new CoerceValueCallback(
            (d, baseValue) =>
            {
                var e = new PropertyChangingEventArgs<TValue>((TValue)baseValue);
                coerceValueCallback((T)d, e);
                return
                    e.Canceled
                    ? DependencyProperty.UnsetValue
                    : e.CoercedValue;
            }
        );
        return this;
    }

    public static implicit operator PropertyMetadata(
        PropertyMetadataBuilder<T, TValue> builder
    )
    {
        return builder._propertyMetadata;
    }
}
```

I initialize it via an extension for the `DependencyPropertyBuilder`.

```
static class DependencyPropertyBuilderExtensions
{
    public static DependencyPropertyBuilder<T, TValue> PropertyMetadata<T, TValue>(
        this DependencyPropertyBuilder<T, TValue> builder,
        Action<PropertyMetadataBuilder<T, TValue>> build
    ) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        var metadataBuilder = new PropertyMetadataBuilder<T, TValue>();
        build(metadataBuilder);
        return builder.Metadata(metadataBuilder);
    }
}
```

Another extension can be added to support the creation of a `FrameworkPropertyMetadata`.

---

The `DependencyPropertyBuilder` has lost the `PropertyMetadata` related APIs and got instead one for setting metadata:

```
public DependencyPropertyBuilder<T, TValue> Metadata(
    PropertyMetadata propertyMetadata
)
{
    _propertyMetadata = propertyMetadata;
    return this;
}
```

---

The missing option `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` to cancel `CoerceValue` is now available via the `PropertyChangingEventArgs`.

This should unify the the property value changing/changed behavior. The `CoerceValue` API is a weird one. It actually handles the property-changing event but in a completely unconventional way.

```
class PropertyChangingEventArgs<TValue> : EventArgs
{
    internal PropertyChangingEventArgs(TValue baseValue)
    {
        NewValue = baseValue;
        CoercedValue = baseValue;
    }
    public TValue NewValue { get; }
    public TValue CoercedValue { get; set; }
    public bool Canceled { get; set; }
}
```

This does not require to use the `UnsetValue` directly as it is determined by the `Canceled` property:

```
public PropertyMetadataBuilder<T, TValue> PropertyChanging(
    Action<T, PropertyChangingEventArgs<TValue>> coerceValueCallback
)
{
    _propertyMetadata.CoerceValueCallback = new CoerceValueCallback(
        (d, baseValue) =>
        {
            var e = new PropertyChangingEventArgs<TValue>((TValue)baseValue);
            coerceValueCallback((T)d, e);
            return
                e.Canceled
                ? DependencyProperty.UnsetValue
                : e.CoercedValue;
        }
    );
    return this;
}
```

---

## Example

The new implementation can be used like this

```
class TestObject : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CountProperty =
        DependencyPropertyBuilder
        .Register<TestObject, int>(nameof(TestObject.Count))
        .PropertyMetadata(b => b
            .DefaultValue(5)
            .PropertyChanged((testObject, e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{e.Property.Name} = {e.OldValue} --> {e.NewValue}");
            })
            .PropertyChanging((testObject, e) =>
            {
                if (e.NewValue > 20)
                {
                    e.CoercedValue = 15;
                }

                if (e.NewValue < 1)
                {
                    e.Canceled = true;
                }
            })
        ).ValidateValue(value => value >= 0);

    public int Count
    {
        get { return CountProperty.GetValue<int>(this); }
        set { CountProperty.SetValue(this, value); }
    }
}
```

Changing `Count` value:

```
var testObject = new TestObject();
testObject.Count.Dump("Default");

testObject.Count2 = 8;
testObject.Count2.Dump("Changed");

testObject.Count = 22;
testObject.Count.Dump("Coerced to max");

testObject.Count = 0;
testObject.Count.Dump("Property change canceled");

testObject.Count = -2; // bam!
```

Output

```
Default    
5 
Count = 5 --> 8    

Changed    
8 
Count = 8 --> 15

Coerced to max    
15 

Property change canceled    
15 

ArgumentException
'-2' is not a valid value for property 'Count'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have combined this builder with the [declarative one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/150965/declarative-dependencyproperety-registration).

---

Now the `Build` resolves the `DefaultValue` and `Validation` attributes on the property:

```
public DependencyProperty Build()
{
    BuildDefaultValue();
    BuildValidateValueCallback();

    return DependencyProperty.Register(
        _name,
        _propertyType,
        _ownerType,
        _propertyMetadata,
        _validateValueCallback
    );
}

private void BuildDefaultValue()
{
    var property = _ownerType.GetProperty(_name);

    // Use the default value specified by the user or try to use the attribute.
    _propertyMetadata.DefaultValue =
        _propertyMetadata.DefaultValue ??
        new Func<object>(() =>
            // Get the defualt value from the attribute...
            property.GetCustomAttribute<DefaultValueAttribute>()?.Value ??
            // or use the default value for the type.
            (property.PropertyType.IsValueType
                ? Activator.CreateInstance(property.PropertyType)
                : null
            )
        )();
}

private void BuildValidateValueCallback()
{
    var property = _ownerType.GetProperty(_name);

    // Use the callback specified by the user or try to use the attributes.
    _validateValueCallback =
        _validateValueCallback ??
        (value =>
            new Func<bool>(() => (
                property.GetCustomAttributes<ValidationAttribute>() ??
                Enumerable.Empty<ValidationAttribute>()
            ).All(x => x.IsValid(value)))()
        );
}
```

---

I changed the `PropertyChanging` API back to `CoerceValue`. The main one works like the WPF implementation:

```
public PropertyMetadataBuilder<T, TValue> CoerceValue(
    Func<T, TValue, object> coerceValueCallback
)
{
    _propertyMetadata.CoerceValueCallback = (d, baseValue) => 
        coerceValueCallback((T) d, (TValue)baseValue);
    return this;
}
```

and I extended it via an extension to work  with `EventArgs`.

```
public static PropertyMetadataBuilder<T, TValue> CoerceValue<T, TValue>(
    this PropertyMetadataBuilder<T, TValue> builder,
    Action<T, CoerceValueEventArgs<TValue>> coerceValueCallback
) where T : DependencyObject
{
    builder.CoerceValue((d, baseValue) =>
    {
        var e = new CoerceValueEventArgs<TValue>(baseValue);
        coerceValueCallback(d, e);
        return
            e.Canceled
                ? DependencyProperty.UnsetValue
                : e.CoercedValue;
    });
    return builder;
}
```

The custom `EventArgs`

```
public class CoerceValueEventArgs<TValue> : EventArgs
{
    internal CoerceValueEventArgs(TValue baseValue)
    {
        NewValue = baseValue;
        CoercedValue = baseValue;
    }
    public TValue NewValue { get; }
    public TValue CoercedValue { get; set; }
    public bool Canceled { get; set; }
}
```

---

This is the new `TestObject`

```
internal class TestObject : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CountProperty =
        DependencyPropertyBuilder
        .Register<TestObject, int>(nameof(Count))
        .PropertyMetadata(b => b
            .PropertyChanged((testObject, e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{e.Property.Name} = {e.OldValue} --> {e.NewValue}");
            })            
            .CoerceValue((testObject, e) =>
            {
                if (e.NewValue > 20)
                {
                    e.CoercedValue = 15;
                }

                if (e.NewValue < 1)
                {
                    e.Canceled = true;
                }
            })
        );

    [DefaultValue(5)]
    [Range(0, 15)]
    public int Count
    {
        get { return CountProperty.GetValue<int>(this); }
        set { CountProperty.SetValue(this, value); }
    }
}
```

and the tests

```
[TestMethod]
public void Count_DefaultValue()
{
    var testObject = new TestObject();
    Assert.AreEqual(5, testObject.Count, "Default value.");
}

[TestMethod]
public void Count_ChangeValue()
{
    var testObject = new TestObject
    {
        Count = 8
    };
    Assert.AreEqual(8, testObject.Count, "Changed value");
}

[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
public void Count_ValueOutOfRange()
{
    new TestObject
    {
        Count = 22
    };
}
```