# Declarative DependencyProperety registration

Tags: c#, wpf, reflection

Most properties have simple requirements so it should be possible to register their Dependency Property fields declaratively.

I made a small experiment and it seems to work just fine. The first attempt supports `DefaultValue` and `Validation` attributes.

It looks a little bit like JavaScript ;-)

---

The new `DependencyPropertyBuilder` loops over fields of type `DependencyProperty`. For each field it gets the necessary data with reflection from the property and its attributes.

```
class DependencyPropertyBuilder
{
    public static void RegisterFor<T>() where T : DependencyObject
    { 
        var fields = typeof(T).GetFields().Where(x => x.FieldType == typeof(DependencyProperty));
        foreach (var field in fields)
        {
            var property = typeof(T).GetProperty(Regex.Replace(field.Name, "Property$", string.Empty));
            field.SetValue(
                null, 
                DependencyProperty.Register(
                    property.Name, 
                    property.PropertyType, 
                    typeof(T), 
                    new PropertyMetadata()
                    {
                        DefaultValue = new Func<object>(() =>
                        {
                            var defaultValue = property.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DefaultValueAttribute)) as DefaultValueAttribute;
                            if (defaultValue != null)
                            {
                                return defaultValue.Value;
                            }

                            // Return the default value for the type.
                            if (property.PropertyType.IsValueType)
                            {
                                return Activator.CreateInstance(property.PropertyType);
                            }
                            return null;
                        })(),
                    }, 
                    new ValidateValueCallback(v => new Func<bool>(() => 
                    {
                        var validations = property.GetCustomAttributes(
                            typeof(ValidationAttribute))?.Cast<ValidationAttribute>() 
                            ?? Enumerable.Empty<ValidationAttribute>();
                        // Evaluate all validators.
                        return validations.All(x => x.IsValid(v));
                    })())
                )
            );
        }
    }
}
```

The new test object is now really short:

```
class TestObject : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CountProperty;

    static TestObject()
    {
        DependencyPropertyBuilder.RegisterFor<TestObject>();
    }

    [DefaultValue(5)]
    [Range(0, 15)]
    public int Count
    {
        get { return CountProperty.GetValue<int>(this); }
        set { CountProperty.SetValue(this, value); }
    }
}
```

The usage is the same:

```
var testObject = new TestObject();
testObject.Count.Dump("Default");

testObject.Count = 8;
testObject.Count.Dump("Changed");

testObject.Count = 22; // bam! out-of-range
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few notes :

> ```
> // Return the default value for the type.
> if (property.PropertyType.IsValueType)
> {
>     return Activator.CreateInstance(property.PropertyType);
> }
> return null;
> ```

You can use ternary operator here

```
// Return the default value for the type.
return property.PropertyType.IsValueType
    ? Activator.CreateInstance(property.PropertyType)
    : null;
```

Those `})()` at the end of your functors are a little bit confusing in my opinion it will be a clearer if you call `.Invoke()` explicitly `}).Invoke()`

> ```
> var validations = property.GetCustomAttributes(
> typeof(ValidationAttribute))?.Cast<ValidationAttribute>()
> ?? Enumerable.Empty<ValidationAttribute>();
> ```

You should be able to specify the type argument explicitly to avoid the `.Cast<T>`

```
var customValidationAttributes = property.GetCustomAttributes<ValidationAttribute>();
var validations = customValidationAttributes ?? Enumerable.Empty<ValidationAttribute>();
```

Comment: `})()` This is what I meant it would look like JavaScript ;-) I thought that there must be the `GetCustomAttributes<T>` method because I used it before but my LINQPad didn't show it somehow, strange. Anyway, good points.